# "Обман" с ссылками

Tags: javascript, ссылки

Подскажите, как сделать, "обман ссылками"? Знаю, не всем понятно, что я вообще имею ввиду, сейчас объясню. Например, имеем ссылку **http://example.com**, но нужно, чтобы при переходе на неё, клиент попадал на **http://example.net**. В основном, можно тупо указать правильную ссылку, но мне нужна "неправильная". Я подумываю сделать это с помощью **onclick**, но в знаниях JavaScript, а не силён. Помогите!

```
<a href="http://example.com" onclick="`**?**`">link</a>
```

Что нужно ввести в onclick, чтобы добиться желаемого результата?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function r(url) {
    top.location.href=url;
    return false;
  }
</script>
<a href="url1" onclick="return r('url2');">text</a>
```

А вот вариант для извращенцев (jquery)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var redirects = {
    'http://bash.im/' : 'http://hashcode.ru/',
    'http://putin2012.ru/' : 'http://хэшкод.рф/',
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
    for (var url in redirects) {
      $('a[href="'+url+'"]').data('rd', {
        url: url,
        red: redirects[url]
      }).mousedown(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        el.attr('href', el.data('rd').red);
      }).mouseup(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
          el.attr('href', el.data('rd').url);
        }, 0);
      });
    }
  });
</script>
<a href="http://bash.im/">test 1</a><br />
<a href="http://putin2012.ru/">test 2</a>
```

Естественно, redirects и функцию лучше где-нибудь спрятать, да хотя бы в подгружаемом файле. Во втором случае бонусы: в хтмл-коде нельзя увидеть реальный URL, даже в скомпилированном; + работают стандартные действия типа ctrl+click, wheelclick.

[`[рабочий код]`](http://sh4dow.jino.ru/test53.php)

Comment: Апдейт, убил жуков, полет нормальный.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery но попроще:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#url').click(function(){
top.location.href='http://example.net';
});
});
</script>
<a id="url" href="http://example.com">тыц</a>
```